# create a customtitlebar at runtime

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a titlebarpanel at runtime.

Calling this procedure from any form's oncreate seems to create the titlebar and shuffle down the existing component positions (needed or the titelbarpanel sites over them), but the titlebar panel is blank.  No caption shows, the button does not show either.

Any ideas on how to do this at runtime?

```
procedure CreateTitleBarPanel(fname:tform);
var titlebarpanel:ttitlebarpanel;
    F1button:tbutton;
    i:integer;
begin
     fname.customtitlebar.enabled:=true;
     titlebarpanel:=ttitlebarpanel.create(fname);
     fname.customtitlebar.control:=titlebarpanel;
     fname.customtitlebar.ShowCaption:=true;
     fname.customtitlebar.ShowIcon:=true;
     F1button:=tbutton.create(titlebarpanel);
     F1button.top:=0;
     F1button.height:=titlebarpanel.height;
     F1button.width:=F1button.height;
     F1button.caption:='F';
     F1button.left:=100;
     //move all form components down to match the titlebar height
     for i:=0 to fname.ComponentCount-1 do
     begin
          try
             (fname.Components[i] as TControl).top:=(fname.Components[i] as TControl).top+fname.customtitlebar.height;
          except
                //control does not have a top property, so skip it
          end;
     end;
     //this seems to report the button position correctly at (0,100) with width and height both 45
     showmessage('DEBUG: F1button.top='+inttostr(F1button.top)+' F1button.left='+inttostr(F1button.left)+' F1button.height='+inttostr(F1button.height)+' F1button.width='+inttostr(F1button.width));
end;
```

To see what happens, create a new form, single button top and right 8.  Then call CreateTitleBarPanel(self) inside OnCreate.

When the program is run the titlebar is created, but there is no caption or system icon top left.  You can still click top left and the usual menu opens, but it does not show.  The button and caption are also hidden.

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You forget to set the `F1button.Parent` to `titlebarpanel`?

Comment: Setting that makes no difference, but thanks for the idea.  The system icon, form caption and button are still not visible within the titlebar area.  But setting titlebarpanel.parent:=fname; fixed it.

Comment: Did you set the `titlebarpanel.Parent`?

Comment: Yes, you beat me to it.  That was the fix.